# Jquery UI Draggable PHP-Jquery Conversion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I have this PHP/Jquery/JqueryUI loop script which makes a range of elements draggable by id and it works fine:-

```
<?php
  $phpid=1;
  while($phpid < 10){
    <script>
      $(function(){$('#<?php echo $phpid ?>').draggable()});
    </script>
  $phpid++;
  }
?>
```

However I need to change it from PHP to Javascript/Jquery/JqueryIU script only. The first thought is:-

```
<script>
  var scriptid=1;
  while (scriptid < 10){
    $(function(){$('#scriptid').draggable()});
  scriptid++;
</script>
```

But this won't work as `scriptid` is inside quotes, so I try:-

```
$(function(){$('#'+scriptid).draggable()});
```

This works but only on the very last element. It's like it's performing the loop counting `scripted` up to 10 then performing the function. I can:-

```
$(function(){$('#'+1).draggable()});
$(function(){$('#'+2).draggable()});
$(function(){$('#'+3).draggable()});
.
.
$(function(){$('#'+10).draggable()});
```

This works fine but I need it to be in a loop. I know the `$(function(){ ..... })` waits for the page to load before executing but dropping it off just gives syntax error.

I think this has a simple, neat solution (possibly using `.each` or `this`) but it's become a time waster for me now. Any ideas thanks?

Comment: You realize IDs shouldn't start with a numeric character, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a class to each element you would like to be dragable,
you should be able to just run it across all elements:

```
$(function(){$('.drag').draggable()});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all your created functions are referencing the variable `scriptid`. When each function is run, it returns the value of `scriptid` at the time the function is run (which will be one more than the limit value for the loop).

Maybe you can try this. You can google for `let`

```
for(let scriptid = 0; i < 10; ++i){
  $(function(){$('#'+scriptid).draggable()});
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for those answers they've provoked me to try this:- `$(function(){$('*:not(body)').draggable()});`. Now this works fie in this case as I'm selecting every element however I have other code later on where I need to use the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with:-

```
  <script>
    var scriptid=1;
    $(function(){
      while (scriptid < 10){
        $('#'+scriptid).draggable();
      scriptid++;
    }});
  </script>
```

I've put this new loop inside the function and this code now precedes my other main loop.

I believe what was happening was the `$(function(){ ... }` was executing after the page had loaded which was after the `scriptid` variable had already counted to its maximum thus only making the final element draggable. Someone may be able to confirm this.

So thanks Patrick & hab55 and anyone else that took a look.